# Is there a way to see what resources from a website from a website have loaded with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

So, for example, I want to see if the favicon loaded, if the html from the page loaded, etc.

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried, what research you've done, etc?

Comment: No, Selenium doesn't support this feature. However you could list them by intercepting the traffic with browsermob-proxy.

Comment: Adding the link for browsermob-proxy. https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy